# getImageList минус 1 условие

Tags: php, cms, modx

скажите как мне сделать условие при выводе чтобы [[*id]]-1 было

```
 [[getImageList?
      &tvname=`slider`
      &tpl=`slider`
      &docid=`1`
      &where=`{"MIGX_id:IN":"id"-[1]}`
]]
```

Comment: что это за кусок кода вообще?

Comment: уберите из тегов javascript. Это modx со своим modx синтаксисом. За таким обращайтесь на modx.pro

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это можно через [фильтры ввода-вывода](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)) modx:

```
&where=`{"MIGX_id:=":"[[*id:decrement=`1`]]"}`
```